# Boolean selectors supplied as URL-embedded parameters do not work in Mongo+Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, meanjs

Mongoose appears to ignore boolean selectors in a query string.

For example, I have a microservice for a blog that exposes API end-points like:

https://myservice.com/post/searchPost?postID=745&tree=true&visible=true

This search pulls out a post with the specified postID with all comments and sub-comments and ignoring those not marked for viewing.

The back-end has a Mongoose model wrapped around a MongoDB collection. I build a query string that I pass to the Mongoose find method, given that there are multiple URL-embedded querying parameters. The string looks like this:

`var queryString = "{$and: [{postID: 745},{postParentIDList: 745},{postIsVisible: false}]}"`

This works except that the boolean values are ignored. Note that the query works just fine.

`Post.find({$and: [{postID: 745},{postParentIDList: 745},{postIsVisible: false}]}, callback(err, doc){// some code}); // A-OK!`

The problem occurs only when the query is passed as as string.

`Post.find(queryString, callback(err, doc){// some code}); // Boolean ignored`

I have tried enclosing the boolean values in the query string in quotes, e.g. postIsVisible: 'false'. That hasn't resolved the issue. Another option is to replace boolean constraints with numeric 0/1. That would entail changing my data model which isn't practical at this point. Besides, it doesn't explain the observed behavior.

I am grateful for any help.

The Mongoose model (sample):

```
postIsVisible :{ // Attribute to support tomake only some post visible
    type        : Boolean,
    required    : true,
    default     : true,
},
postHeadline :{ //Headline of the Post, provided by user
    type        : String,
},
postDescription :{ //Decription of the Post, provided by user
    type        : String,
    required    : true,
},
```

And so on.

Comment: Can you provide more information on PostIsSchema attribute definition ( I.e. exact syntax) and sample document?

Comment: The mongoose model is straightforward. I have edited the question and put in a sample.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So is `queryString` a _string_ or an _object_?

Comment: It is a string, constructed by an if-else ladder that parses the URL for tokens. I pass the string to the find() method of the Mongoose model. I have put in an edit to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: @SunBee interesting, because AFAIK, you can't pass query _strings_ to `find()`. [The documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find) states that it should be an object. Are you sure that it actually works properly? Passing a string for me seems to act similarly to `find({})` (ie, it returns all documents).